# Spotify wep api could not find existing item

Tags: python, spotify

i am trying to recover spotify ID's of some tracks i got title and artist, and while i was trying to complete the task i came across a strange situation:

the track is the following:
"artist" : "Noisettes",
"track" : "Don't Upset The Rhythm (Go Baby Go)"

The track exists and seems written the same way (so no spaces, strange characters), i manually found the spotifyid of the item ("6Pfp47eUtnj2D1LMMtmDne"), but when i perform the search specifing this query parameter

```
q=artist%3ANoisettes+track%3ADon%27t+Upset+The+Rhythm+%28Go+Baby+Go%29&type=track
```

by the search for item
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/search
it returns a response with 0 items, meaning it didn't match any item.
Do you have an idea why this happens?